# django deployment on Heroku KeyError: 'MAILGUN_API_KEY'

Tags: django, heroku, cookiecutter-django

I m using cookie cutter but did not select Heroku deployment in selection list when creating app.

but now, I want it on Heroku.
I've this error:

```
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
remote:            raise KeyError(key) from None
remote:        KeyError: 'MAILGUN_API_KEY'
remote:        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 31, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 231, in fetch_command
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
remote:            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/tmp/build_3a322b24/config/settings/production.py", line 132, in <module>
remote:            "MAILGUN_API_KEY": env("MAILGUN_API_KEY"),
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 123, in __call__
remote:            return self.get_value(var, cast=cast, default=default, parse_default=parse_default)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 277, in get_value
remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the MAILGUN_API_KEY environment variable
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
```

packages installed are:

```
remote:        Installing collected packages: pytz, text-unidecode, python-slugify, Pillow, pycparser, cffi, six, argon2-cffi, redis, hiredis, sqlparse, asgiref, django, django-environ, django-model-utils, defusedxml, python3-openid, oauthlib, urllib3, chardet, idna, certifi, requests, requests-oauthlib, cryptography, pyjwt, django-allauth, django-crispy-forms, django-redis, bootstrap4, whitenoise, gunicorn, psycopg2, typing-extensions, python-dateutil, jmespath, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, django-storages, Collectfast, django-anymail
remote:        Successfully installed Collectfast-2.2.0 Pillow-8.2.0 argon2-cffi-20.1.0 asgiref-3.4.0 bootstrap4-0.1.0 boto3-1.17.101 botocore-1.20.101 certifi-2021.5.30 cffi-1.14.5 chardet-4.0.0 cryptography-3.4.7 defusedxml-0.7.1 django-3.1.12 django-allauth-0.44.0 django-anymail-8.2 django-crispy-forms-1.11.2 django-environ-0.4.5 django-model-utils-4.1.1 django-redis-4.12.1 django-storages-1.11.1 gunicorn-20.1.0 hiredis-1.1.0 idna-2.10 jmespath-0.10.0 oauthlib-3.1.1 psycopg2-2.9.1 pycparser-2.20 pyjwt-2.1.0 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-slugify-5.0.2 python3-openid-3.2.0 pytz-2021.1 redis-3.5.3 requests-2.25.1 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 s3transfer-0.4.2 six-1.16.0 sqlparse-0.4.1 text-unidecode-1.3 typing-extensions-3.10.0.0 urllib3-1.26.6 whitenoise-5.2.0
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

what should I add  to make it works

Comment: What are you email settings? The environment/django can't access your API key and it looks like this relates to your email service.

Comment: i m using mailgun and put infos in my .env. in production.py I Have: EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.mailgun.EmailBackend"
ANYMAIL = {
    "MAILGUN_API_KEY": env("MAILGUN_API_KEY"),
    "MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN": env("MAILGUN_DOMAIN"),
    "MAILGUN_API_URL": env("MAILGUN_API_URL", default="https://api.mailgun.net/v3"),
}. I did not change anything in base.py

Comment: And is `MAILGUN_API_KEY` defined in the heroku config vars? Some details here if needed; https://blog.learncodeonline.in/deploy-your-django-postgresql-web-application-on-heroku-with-environment-variables

Comment: yes I put all of this in .env (respecting Cookiecutter app settings

Comment: Does Heroku respect that .env file? I would suggest creating a new dummy project with the Heroku option to yes and examine the difference.\